# How can I typecast PVOID to get exact struct or data type for any variable in C++

Tags: c++, c, types, driver, windows-kernel

I am working in Windows kernel mode drivers and want to know about the exact datatype of the PVOID/HANDLE variables from which I may typecast them to a suitable datatype.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer the question. PVOID/HANDLE is an untyped pointer. You need to use other means to determine what the pointer type is.

Comment: @RaymondChen like I am using NtCreateFile and it has a parameter of HANDLE type, I want to know what is inside the HANDLE parameter. how I may cast it to get exact result?

Comment: There is nothing inside the handle. All you can do with the handle is pass it to a function that accepts handles.

Comment: That might be platform-dependent. It might help to list your target hardware/OSes if you want to treat it as a type which isn't opaque.

Comment: @RaymondChen and what about the PVOID? Can we get there exact datatypes?

Comment: From my understanding, Microsoft used to love Hungarian Notation. But "P" prefix is the least informative since all it meant was "pointer".  It could be 16-bit in some cases, 32-bits in others, 64-bits in others. It would point to something but that's about all we could gather -- hardly the type of info you could rely on if you are programming embedded.

Comment: @DragonEnergy So there is no other way around that we may get the exact structures for VOID types?

Comment: @abdullahtoqeer Unfortunately they wouldn't alias the types if we were meant to be able to get to them exactly. If you are willing to give up portability, I think it's okay to x-ray.... in prototypes I often assume `PVOID` or `LPVOID` to match `void*`, whatever. But you know, prototypes.

Comment: my main concern is to see inside the returned structures(VOID types) from windows kernel APIs, e.g. `NTSTATUS NtAcceptConnectPort(PHANDLE PortHandle, PVOID PortContext, PPORT_MESSAGE ConnectionRequest, BOOLEAN AcceptConnection, PPORT_VIEW ServerView, PREMOTE_PORT_VIEW ClientView);`
is a windows API and there is PortContext of PVOID type, I just want to know what is inside PortContext?

Comment: @abdullahtoqeer you have been told by a Microsoft insider that you can't peer inside the types behind the void pointers. The info you seek is not available. Move on. Also, the declaration you show appears to be based on [this page](http://www.codewarrior.cn/ntdoc/wrk/lpc/NtAcceptConnectPort.htm) which has different info than [this page](https://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Port/NtAcceptConnectPort.html).

Comment: @RemyLebeau this function was just an example. BTW thanks to all for helping.

Comment: That's a context parameter. It means whatever the caller wants it to mean. NtAcceptConnectPort doesn't do anything with the pointer except give it back to the caller later.